# Use of '&' in CSS

Tags: css, scss-mixins

I got this CSS online and when I copy-paste this onto a code editor, I'm getting errors (multiple errors) starting with the first (&) in the code below. Could someone help me understand why this is happening? I haven't used & previously in CSS so don't know how it works.

```
body,html{
    background: #efefef;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn{
    border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle {
    display: none;
    & + label{
        cursor: pointer;
        min-width: 60px;
        &:hover{
            background: none;
            color: #1a1a1a;
        }
        &:after{
            background: #1a1a1a;
            content: "";
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
            width: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
        }
    }
    &.toggle-left + label {
        border-right: 0;
        &:after{
            left: 100%
        }
    }
    &.toggle-right + label{
        margin-left: -5px;
        &:after{
            left: -100%;
        }
    }
    &:checked + label {
        cursor: default;
        color: #fff;
        transition: color 200ms;
        &:after{
            left: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that's not CSS, for starters...

Comment: May I suggest that "copy code from the Internet that I don't understand, ask question on Stack Overflow when it doesn't work" might not be the best way to approach things?

Comment: Doesn't look valid to me- what did you actually copy?

Comment: I think this is scss or less. Check file name from where you copy it

Answer (score 3):

That's [LESS](http://lesscss.org) or [SCSS](https://sass-lang.com/), not CSS.

From the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector):

> The parent selector, `&`, is a special selector invented by Sass that’s
> used in nested selectors to refer to the outer selector. It makes it
> possible to re-use the outer selector in more complex ways, like
> adding a pseudo-class or adding a selector before the parent.

The code you added can be converted into CSS:

```css
body,
html {
    background: #efefef;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.btn {
    border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle {
    display: none;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 60px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
    background: none;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
    background: #1a1a1a;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
    border-right: 0;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
    left: 100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
    margin-left: -5px;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
    left: -100%;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
    cursor: default;
    color: #fff;
    transition: color 200ms;
}
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't pure CSS, it's probably for some pre processor like SCSS. You can convert it to real CSS though by hand (if it's not too long overall of course) by going down through the nesting and inserting the specific selector 'parents' instead of the ampersands. Here's an example of the first one:

```
   input[type="radio"].toggle {
        display: none;
        }
     input[type="radio"].toggle + label{
            cursor: pointer;
            min-width: 60px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the SCSS code you can use a [VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass) for compiling the code before you check it on the browser or you can use the following CSS code or you can use an online website to [convert the SCSS To CSS](https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css).

```css
body, html {
     background: #efefef;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     min-height: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
}
 .btn {
     border: 3px solid #1a1a1a;
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 10px;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     transition: background 600ms ease, color 600ms ease;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle {
     display: none;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
     cursor: pointer;
     min-width: 60px;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle + label:hover {
     background: none;
     color: #1a1a1a;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle + label:after {
     background: #1a1a1a;
     content: "";
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     transition: left 200ms cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1);
     width: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label {
     border-right: 0;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-left + label:after {
     left: 100%;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label {
     margin-left: -5px;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle.toggle-right + label:after {
     left: -100%;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
     cursor: default;
     color: #fff;
     transition: color 200ms;
}
 input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label:after {
     left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Clearly you haven't experienced the joy of using sass
here's a crash course that's super easy to comprehend:
[YouTube video link](https://youtu.be/Zz6eOVaaelI)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.